# renewenvironment to change default color of tcolorbox

Tags: environments, tcolorbox, optional-arguments

I want to change the default background color of the \tcolorbox environment. I really like /.append style but I know that's a TiKZ thing.

When you uncomment the \renewenvironment in the header, Overleaf gives this warning:

> TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].

I tried some variations on it but I can't seem to fix the problem.

It seems like the available documentation for \newenvironment is a lot more thorough than for \renewenvironment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

%%%%%%%%%This didn't work in the header. I tried putting in [1] and that didn't seem to matter
%\renewenvironment{tcolorbox}{\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white]}{\end{tcolorbox}}


\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
The default background is gray
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white]
    I want it to default to white
\end{tcolorbox}


\end{document}
```

[image: tcolorboxes mwe]

Comment: You can use `\tcbset{colback=white}` to set a different "default". (The cleaner option may be to define your own style with all the "default" values you want, and use the style wherever needed.)

Answer (score 0):

@user26305 answered in a comment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{colback=white} %This fixed it

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
The default background has been changed from gray to white!
\end{tcolorbox}


\end{document}
```

Thank you!